# TDD Model View Presenter using MOQ

Tags: c#, tdd, moq

I've seen a video using TDD and the MVP pattern to create a small application.  This video is shown here:

http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/content/binary/appliedTestDrivenDevelopmentPart3/appliedtestdrivendevelopmentpart3.swf.

The video uses Rhino Mocks, could anybody shed some light on how you can achive the same test using MOQ.

So if i had the following code below how would i write a test (using MOQ) to test the Init() method?

```
public interface IGui
{
   event eventhandler UpdateFromDataSource;
} 

public class Gui :IGui
{
   button.Click += delegate { UpdateFromDataSource(); }   
}

public class GuiPresenter
{
    IGui gui;
    public GuiPresenter(IGui gui)
    {
       this.gui = gui;
    }

    public Init()
    {
        gui.UpdateFromDataSource += delegate {//something};
    }
}
```

Thanks

CA

Answer (score 0):

If Init() does not produce any desirable output, I wouldn't bother testing the Init method on the GuiPresenter.

What are you trying to test?

Answer (score 0):

I want to test that the GUI UpdateFromDataSource event has a wired up handler.  So i want to be able to create a Mock of GUI and test that when Init gets called that the Gui Mock objects 
UpdateFromDataSource has at least one event handler.

I want to get a similar test to the one in this video.  http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/content/binary/appliedTestDrivenDevelopmentPart3/appliedtestdrivendevelopmentpart3.swf.

The video uses Rhino Mock not Moq!

Comment: You could always cast the event to a Delegate and then assert how many there are. Don't remember the exact members to use, but I know they are there. That said, these tests only verifies the events have listeners. You still don't know if they are the correct listeners or if they do the right thing. Test the outcome: What do you want to happen when the button is clicked. And forget about that video, that's just one approach out of many.

Answer (score 0):

I have bad experience with approaches based on events like that. It's harder to mock and test, as you have discovered, but you are also replacing easier code with harder one without really gaining anything: You still have to write the glue code to activate those events. Events can also turn into memory leaks if not released properly, or nasty bugs because it's harder to navigate in code.

I find it easier to turn these events into presenter methods and let the view call them directly. It's easier to test, and it's harder to write tests against the mocks, which is pretty meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to test that Init is hooking up the View's event to the corresponding handler in the presenter.

I would create

- a mock view
- pass it into a presenter instance
- raise the mock event e.g. `mockView.Raise( m => m.UpdateDataSource()+= null )`
- verify the change in state in the presenter that should occur if the handler (`//something`) is called